# History question about the difference quotient: what does "h" mean?

Tags: limits, derivatives, notation, math-history

Regarding the difference quotient (f(x+h) - f(x)/h), what is the origin of the usage of "h"? Does it mean anything?

Thank you!

Comment: No idea.  (H)orizontal displacement?

Comment: If always reminded me of the abscissa in $y=a(x-h)^2+k$

Comment: In French it doesn't.

Comment: Did you know that history of science and mathematics has its own SE site?

Answer (score 4):

Isaac Newton (1671) used $o$ in his method of fluxions, meaning a [infinitely small increment](https://books.google.it/books?id=WyQOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA24) of the "independent variable" (implicitly: *time*).

G.W. Leibniz (1676) used the [differentials](https://books.google.it/books?id=tCmp_c3Q9S8C&pg=PA124) : $dx, dy, dz$.

Augustin-Louis Cauchy, in his [Cours (1821)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse) uses $\alpha$ for ["an infinitely small quantity"](https://books.google.it/books?id=M0or-HGe7D0C&pg=PA22).

But $h$ is used in Cauchy's [Resumé (1823)](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA7), page 7 :

> Let $h$ and $i$ two distict quantities, the first one finite, and the second one infinitely small, and let $\alpha = \dfrac i h$ their infinitely small ratio. If we put $\Delta x$ as the finite value $h$, the value of the equation
>
> > $\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)- f(x)$
>
> will be called the *finite difference* of the function $f(x)$, and it will be an ordinary finite quantity.

See also [Resumé](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA9), page 9 :

> > $\dfrac {\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \dfrac {f(x+i)-f(x)}{i}.$

I think that, as long as $i$ become the "standard" name for the imaginary unit, it left place to $h$ as the "standard" name for the increment.

Comment: Thank you so much!